# How to send real time notification to single user using symfony API?

Tags: symfony, push-notification

I'm trying to add a real time notification to my Symfony project but i don't know how.

I need some informations because this is my first project with Symfony.

Comment: welcome. what do you mean by "Symfony API"? ApiPlatform, a custom REST API, Symfony Framework? Which frontend are you using? We cannot guess. And what does "real time notification" mean in your world?

Comment: i'm using ReactJs for frontend and Symfony for the Backend, real time notification like facebook notifications

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to send real time messages is [MercureBundle](https://symfony.com/blog/symfony-gets-real-time-push-capabilities).
However, this may be done via WebSockets or even Socket.IO.